# MAP estimate for a discrete prior

Tags: probability, bayesian, maximum-likelihood

The prior has a form such that it is $0.5$ for $\theta=0.6$ or $\theta=0.2$ and $0$ elsewhere.
The likelihood function $P(D|h)$ has Bernoulli form.

Hence, posterior is $0.5P(D|h)$ for $\theta=0.6$ or $\theta=0.2$ and $0$ elsewhere.

When I calculate the MAP estimate, it comes out to be independent of theta as $N_1/N$ which is same value as obtained from uniform prior, which is strange.

If we change prior such that it is $0.4$ for $\theta=0.6$ and $0.6$ for $\theta=0.2$ and $0$ elsewhere, the MAP estimate still comes out to be same.

Is it correct to say that such discrete prior has no effect on MAP estimate?

Comment: I do not understand.  The MAP (i.e. the mode of the posterior distribution) must lie in the support of the prior distribution, which in this case seems to be $\{0.2,0.6\}$.  So here it cannot be $\frac{N_1}{N}$ unless that is $0.2$ or $0.6$.  Do you mean MLE rather than MAP?

Comment: I mean MAP and I am trying to understand what happens if we have prior as {0.2,0.6}. When I solve for the given set of values, my MAP estimate comes to be same as MLE estimate.

Comment: See what happens when $N_1=9$ and $N=23$ with your two priors so $\frac{N_1}{N}\approx 0.39 \not \in \{0.2,0.6\}$.  Note that if your interpretation of MLE is restricted to choosing between $0.2$ and $0.6$ then giving a prior probability of $50\%$ to each is in effect a uniform prior on those two values

Comment: @Henry That is correct. However, when we actually calculate the MAP estimate by taking derivative, it becomes independent of given prior ({0.2,0.6}).. which is exactly my concern.

Comment: @NKR If the prior only has two-point support, the MAP chooses the greater posterior between those two points. No derivatives (pls see my updated reply).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A MAP estimator maximizes

$$\underbrace{f(\theta|x)}_{\text{posterior}}\propto \underbrace{f(x|\theta)}_{\text{likelihood}}\underbrace{f(\theta)}_{\text{prior}}$$

with respect to $\theta$. In general, the MAP estimator will depend on both the likelihood and the prior since both depend on $\theta$. In the special case of a uniform prior, $f(\theta)$ is constant, so the MAP estimator coincides with the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) (assuming the prior contains the MLE in its support).

---

In your setup, if your data $x_i$ is iid Bernoulli($\theta$), and your prior for $\theta$ has two-point support $\{\theta_1,\theta_2\}$ with respective hyperparameter masses $p,1-p\in (0,1)$ then for $x_i\in \{0,1\},$

$$f(x|\theta)=\Pi_i\theta^x_i (1-\theta)^{1-x_i}=\theta^{\sum_i x_i}(1-\theta)^{n-\sum_i x_i},\\
f(\theta)=p^{\frac{\theta-\theta_2}{\theta_1-\theta_2}}(1-p)^{\frac{\theta-\theta_1}{\theta_2-\theta_1}}\bf{1}_{\theta\in \{\theta_1,\theta_2\}}.$$

The log posterior for $\theta\in\{\theta_1,\theta_2\}$ is

$$\small \log f(\theta|x)=\text{const}+\sum_i x_i\log \theta+(n-\sum_i x_i)\log (1-\theta)+\frac{\theta-\theta_2}{\theta_1-\theta_2}\log p +\frac{\theta-\theta_1}{\theta_2-\theta_1}\log (1-p)$$

So to find the MAP, you just have to check which of $\theta_1,\theta_2$ gives a higher log posterior. Equivalently, letting $\bar x:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i x_i,$

$$\small \hat \theta_{\text{MAP}}={\arg\max}_{\theta\in\{\theta_1,\theta_2\}}\left\{ \bar x\log \theta+(1-\bar x)\log (1-\theta)+\left(\frac{1}{n}\log p\right){\bf 1}_{\theta=\theta_1}+\left(\frac{1}{n}\log (1-p)\right){\bf 1}_{\theta=\theta_2}\right\}.$$

The estimator depends on data and prior hyperparameters ($\theta_1,\theta_2,p$). But it is possible that for a particular data set, a small change in $p$ will not change the MAP estimator.

Comment: In general, the MAP estimator depends on both likelihood and the prior, since both are functions of $\theta$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
For my case, p=0.5. This means third term in FOC would become 0. So it seems that we would get the same value of  as with uniform prior. Please me know if thats correct.

Comment: True, the third term is zero if $p=0.5$ (this is a discrete uniform prior). More generally, the MAP coincides with MLE under a uniform prior (assuming the prior contains the MLE in its support). But it is incorrect to say *any discrete prior* has no effect on the MAP estimate; in your setup, you can see the third term in the FOC is strictly monotonic in $p$ so it varies uniquely with the masses assigned to your two-point prior (e.g. it would not be zero if $p=0.4$ as you mentioned in your question).

Comment: To make sure I understood it correctly, for prior with two-point support `{x1, x2}` with p=0.5, MAP coincides with MLE (with bernoulli dist). However, with any other value of p, this might not be true.

Comment: Yes, do you see why it is not true for other values of $p$ though?

Comment: Yes.. thank you very much!

Comment: @NKR ok no prob!

Comment: @NKR It occurred to me the FOC is the wrong approach in your case because with two point support prior, you only have to plug in those 2 points into your objective. At other points, the prior assigns zero mass so the posterior is zero.

Comment: @NKR Sorry about the confusion, let me work through it and update my response

Comment: @NKR Let me know if the update now makes sense

Comment: I think I understand it now.. thank you for the explanation!